# Date Time Converter for Room which support Api 24 and Api 26

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-format

Below is helper class for room which convert Instant to Long for sqlite. The problem is my device is on Api 24 and I am using feature only available on Api 26. How can I support this without adding additional library?

```
   class DateConverter {
        companion object {
            @TypeConverter
            @JvmStatic
            fun fromInstant(value: Instant): Long {
                return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    value.toEpochMilli()
                } else {
                    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
                }
            }

            @TypeConverter
            @JvmStatic
            fun toInstant(value: Long): Instant {
                return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    Instant.ofEpochMilli(value)
                } else {
                    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ThreeTen Android Backport library:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Then just update your import to `org.threeten.bp.Instant` and remove the version check.

Comment: so there is no way that i can achieve without external lib?

Comment: Well you don't have to, but then that means going back to the not so great older Java APIs

Comment: I’d seriously consider this library. It’s only until once you move to API level 26 (or higher).

Answer (score 0):

As you know you can't use `Instant`. You need to use ordinal `long`, `Date` or other libraries.
You use `ofEpochMilli(long)` so it is almost same with `new Date(long)`.